# Make viewcode show module sources

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to make a cookbook out of some Python snippets using Sphinx. Each snippet is a self-contained Python script and has a tutorial-type doctsring.

I want to have a source link in the generated documentation to display the script contents. But [viewcode](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/viewcode.html) does not seem to create this link for the module, but only for a function or a class with a docstring. Is there a way to coax [`sphinx.ext.viewcode`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/viewcode.html) to display the script code without having any class/function in it?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you haven't sat for two years waiting for an answer, but try using the literal include tag. You can play around with what gets displayed.

See [the sphinx docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.8/markup/code.html#includes) for more details.