# When documenting with Sphinx, how do I insert [source] links manually

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using the `sphinx.ext.viewcode` extension to generate `[source]` links to classes and functions.

This works great for documentation produced via `autodoc`, but there doesn't seem to be any restructured-text syntax available for me to make my own links.

I tried getting Sphinx to dump an rst version of its output, but that contains no trace of any markup relating to source code links.

EDIT: To be more specific, I do get proper source links when applying directives such as `.. py:function: somefunction`, but for a page documenting a single module I would like the header to have a [source] link to the module file, but `.. py:module: mymodule` does not produce such a link, and neither does `..automodule::`.

I guess I'm really asking the underlying question of: How does `viewcode` decide where to put in `[source]` links and how can I control it?

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/25565677/407651

Comment: @mzjn: Yes, that does look very similar.